# Web API: Product set use default status for store view

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rest-api, store-view

Our products are created and updated via the web API. When we update a product for all `/rest/all/V1/products/123` and set `status: 2` the product is disabled. But per store view it's still enabled because the checkbox "Use Default Value" is not checked.

I tried to send `use_default_status: 1` per store view (`rest/german/V1/products/123`)like this:

```
{
  "product": {
  "sku": "123",
  "name": "My Product",
  "use_default_status": 1
  }
}
```

But then I get the following error:

> Property "UseDefaultStatus" does not have accessor method "getUseDefaultStatus" in class "Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface"

Is it somehow possible to set the `use_default_status` checkbox via web API? The best would be if I could set it without having to push the product for the store view.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? Thank you

Comment: Hi unfortunately I did not. I think we did a workaround where we set it via sql for all the products.